# Microsoft office-ui-fabric-react vs fluent-ui-react - which to choose?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

These projects seem closely related. Someone from the office-ui-fabric team made the following comment in August 2019:

> We're actually in the middle of working with MSFT marketing team to somehow change this to not be branded as Office only. We are trying to become the primary way to create React (web) applications with the Fluent design language.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/10251#issuecomment-524402520

But the flient-ui-react website states:

> Fluent UI React is being built as an exemplar of the Fluent UI design language, component specifications, and utilities.

https://microsoft.github.io/fluent-ui-react

Is fluent-ui-react simply a lighter weight alternative, an eventual replacement or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://microsoft.github.io/fluent-ui-react has been archived in the last few days, so I guess Microsoft answered this question :)

Comment: what do you mean, archived? It is still active.
"...so that at any time you can use the new @fluentui/react package with no breaking changes."

Answer (score 4):

UI Fabric became Fluent UI, full story here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/ui-fabric-is-evolving-into-fluent-ui/

Answer (score 0):

As of version 8, the office-ui-fabric-react package has been discontinued in favor of @fluentui/react: [office-ui-fabric-react to @fluentui/react](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Version-8-migration-guide#office-ui-fabric-react-to-fluentuireact)

Answer (score 0):

Saw the following on the Fluent UI Git Hub page:
https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui

> The Office UI Fabric React project has evolved to Fluent UI.

*The office-ui-fabric-react repo is now this repo (fluentui in the Microsoft organization)! The name change should not disrupt any current Fabric usage, repo clones, pull requests or issue reporting. Links should redirect to the new location. The library formerly known as office-ui-fabric-react is now available as @fluentui/react (see above table for more information).*